# wkwebview cant loading base url from documentsURL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

`Webkit` loading from .documentsURL html webpages, iOS device is not showing image, js, css files, works fine on simulators. What could be my bug in the code I have written?

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let documentsURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath, isDirectory: true)

        let urltostr = documentsURL.absoluteString
        //print(urltostr)
        let htmlurl = urltostr+"0/index.html"
        let finalURL = URL(string: htmlurl)
        let base = urltostr+"0/"
        let baseUrl = URL(string: base)
        //let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: base, isDirectory: true)
        do {
            let fileName  = try String(contentsOf: finalURL!)
            webview.loadHTMLString(fileName as String, baseURL: baseUrl)
        } catch {
            // catch error
            print("Error web view get html")
        }
```

Comment: Even I am also facing the same problem.
Did u get any solution ?

Comment: Yes i solved!, when you loading html string have to set access to read webview.loadFileURL(finalURL!, allowingReadAccessTo: documentsURL)